# I'm updating my pg_hba.conf, but the file gets reset to default everyday

Tags: django, pg-hba.conf

I've made my django instance accessible on pg_hba.conf. But every morning when I go to get started, I have to re-apply the changes because the file has reset back to its original content.

This is a CentOS7 Server running Apache with cpanel, the django instance is setup with gunicorn and nginx on a separate port from Apache's httpd. I've applied the changes to pg_hba.conf and issued the following commands but they do not fix the issue.
    sudo systemctl restart postgresql
    sudo service postgresql restart

here is the code I placed into pg_hba file:

```
local all all peer 
host all all 165.227.123.167/32 md5
host all all ::1/128 md5

#That code successfully allows access to database once applied to file and this command following:
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

I expected the change to be permanent, but it actually needs to be done daily.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. I'm hosted at bluehost. Did you found any solution?

Comment: Sadly. I never found the solution for this and ended up abandoning the django setup. If someone has a solution please share!

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the pg_hba file close it. Restart your postgres service. It'll work.

For security purpose you cant see pg_hba file content.